# Render stops after 1 frame. "Render error (Permission denied) cannot save: '0001.png'"

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, render-layers, error

For some reason today I can no longer render more than 1 frame at a time. I was able to just fine yesterday. After successfully rendering the first frame, render stops and I get this error message:

> Render error (Permission denied) cannot save: '0001.png'

I tried saving output to local drive instead of server but no luck.

I am using the "File output" node in the compositing node editor, and NOT using the render settings output path. I just tried putting something in the output path and leaving the composite nodes untouched, and now it renders fine but renders each frame twice (once for the File Output node, and once for the render settings output path.)

Why would I get this error?

I realize I've found a workaround where I just have to delete the extra renders, but I want to get to the bottom of this problem. ;)

Thanks!

Comment: 1. The permission denied error is probably caused by the write permissions you set for the output folder and the user running the blender process (thus OS specific)
2. If you use the file output node AND click the render animation button both will save each frame, resulting in duplicates

Comment: This error can appears when you open Blender two times.

Answer (score 1):

On output property tab type /tmp\ into the Output file path.

Comment: This worked as a solution for me. Apparently not having any path in the Output folder field causes that error. As a matter of fact, by default there is "/tmp\" as path, which I'm guessing sends those files in a temp folder that then gets wiped out clean. Thank you for this solution, should be marked as solution instead of downvoted.

Comment: What's the difference between `Preferences > File Paths > Render Output` and `Output Properties tab > (input field)`?