# render won’t save “cannot read permission dennied”

Tags: rendering

i'm new to blender, i'm trying to save my rendered image but i keep getting this error, how to fix it? thanks
Image link: https://www.instagram.com/p/CwU98i5MC-4/?igshid=MzRlODBiNWFlZA==

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119851/render-stops-after-1-frame-render-error-permission-denied-cannot-save-0001 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33105/why-do-i-get-a-permission-denied-error-when-importing-an-obj-file https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84602/cannot-save-blend-files-permission-denied

Comment: i tried to post a simple image but it said that the image was large